# On destroying session via Devise "Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm running Rails 5.1.2 and Ruby 2.4.0.

I've created a method in the ApplicationController called `require_login` that checks if the user is logged in order not. If and only if they aren't logged in, they are forwarded to the login page.

The problem is that when I sign them out, I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/sign_out
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out
```

With the culprit line being:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) # right here
    authorize @user
end
```

from my UserController.

This is my code:

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  include Pundit

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  def require_login
    unless signed_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to login_path # halts request cycle
    end
  end

end
```

**UsersController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

My **layouts/topnav.html.erb** where someone can sign out

```
<div class="row border-bottom">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" method="post" action="/">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for something..." class="form-control" name="top-search" id="top-search" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li>
                <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users


  get "home/index"
  get "home/minor"
  root to: 'home#index'

end
```

Also `rake routes` outputs the following:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                              visitors#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                    page GET    /pages/*id                     high_voltage/pages#show
```

What can I do in order for a person to get forwarded to the Login page if they are not authenticated and how can I probably destroy their session so that when they sign out they are properly forwarded to the login page?

Comment: can you post your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: Show us your routes.

Comment: @m.simonborg routes.rb posted! sorry about that.

Comment: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/issues/4

Comment: thanks! output of `rake routes` might be helpful too

Comment: @m.simonborg added :)

Comment: @Pavan add routes. thanks.

Comment: try `redirect_to new_user_session_url`

Comment: Try moving `resources :users` above `devise_for :users`

Comment: @m.simonborg unfortunately no luck :/

Comment: @Pavan no luck :/ makes me lose a lot of my `devise/user` routes. 

got the following error:
`No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"`

Comment: I changed that route helper to the proper `new_user_session_url`, i had a typo before. if that doesn't work then @Pavan 's suggestion might work

Comment: Can you post the full error log?

Comment: sorry but did you try the correct route helper after i fixed my typo? new_user_session_url should send a GET to users/sign_in

Comment: @m.simonborg I tried but with no luck (thank you so much for your help though). puneet18's comment about changing `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get` was the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources :users` and `devise_for :users` are conflict so

try below code:

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  #resources :users //comment the users resources because its already used by devise_for or used some other resources for users


  get "home/index"
  get "home/minor"
  root to: 'home#index'

end
```

Additionally, in your `config/initalizer/devise.rb` file

Change `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get`

Comment: this results in `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"` unfortunately

Comment: goto `config/initalizer/devise.rb` and change line `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get`

Comment: No, they are not in conflict. You have to use ```devise_for :users```  first and then ```resources :users```afterwards. I'm using ruby 2.4.x and 2.5.x with rails 4.2.x to 5.1.5 on different applications.

Answer (score 2):

You've done everything right. The only missing thing is the `:method => :delete` call. This is rails specific and you need *rails-ujs* or for older rails version *jquery_ujs* to make it work.

Add this to your *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*:

```
# for rails 5.1 or higher
//= require rails-ujs

# for rails 5.0 or lower
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

If you don't add this, the `method: :delete` call will not work. If you don't want to use it at all, then change sign_out to work with *GET*.

Change or add this to your *config/initializers/devise.rb*:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

If it's still not working, then you have the wrong order in your *config/routes.rb* file. `devise_for :users` must be before `resources :users`:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

Comment: The above is true for Rails 5.1 + if you are using webpacker for asset compilation, otherwise, the `jquery_ujs` method is still the way to go. For me, I needed that, I did not use `sign_out_via = :get`, but I had to ensure my devise sign out link included `method: :delete` ala `= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'nav__link', method: :delete)`